# Ruby regex matching strings from an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm sort of new to regexs with Ruby, (or I suppose regex in general), but I was wondering if there was a pragmatic way to match a string using an array?

Let me explain, say I have a list of ingredients in this case:

```
1 1/3 cups all-purpose flour
2 teaspoons ground cinnamon
8 ounces shredded mozzarella cheese
```

Ultimately I need to split the ingredients into its respective "quantity and measurement" and "ingredient name", so like in the case of `2 teaspoons ground cinnamon`, will be split into "`8 ounces`, and `shredded mozzarella cheese`.

So Instead of having a hugely long regex like: `(cup\w*|teaspoon\w*ounce\w* ....... )`, how can I use an array to hold those values outside the regex?

---

**update**

I did this (thanks [cwninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963546/ruby-regex-matching-strings-from-an-array/3964632#3964632)):

```
  # I think the all units should be just singular, then 
  # use ruby function to pluralize them.

units = [
  'tablespoon',
  'teaspoon',
  'cup',
  'can',
  'quart',
  'gallon',
  'pinch',
  'pound',
  'pint',
  'fluid ounce',
  'ounce'
  # ... shortened for brevity
]

joined_units = (units.collect{|u| u.pluralize} + units).join('|')

# There are actually many ingredients, so this is actually an iterator
# but for example sake we are going to just show one.
ingredient = "1 (10 ounce) can diced tomatoes and green chilies, undrained"

ingredient.split(/([\d\/\.\s]+(\([^)]+\))?)\s(#{joined_units})?\s?(.*)/i)
```

This gives me close to what I want, so I think this is the direction I want to go.

```
puts "measurement: #{arr[1]}"
puts "unit: #{arr[-2] if arr.size > 3}"
puts "title: #{arr[-1].strip}"
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Personally I'd just build the regexp programmatically, you can do:

```
ingredients = [...]
recipe = Regexp.new(ingredients.join("|"), Regex::IGNORECASE)
```

or using `union` method:

```
recipe = Regexp.union(ingredients)
recipe = /#{regex}/i
```

… then use the `recipe` regexp.

As long as you save it and don't keep recreating it, it should be fairly efficient.

Comment: i also use this approach, with a little tweak:
Regexp.union(measurements) instead of Regexp.new(measurements.join("|")), same result, much cleaner

Comment: This looks good but I believe you mean:

`recipe = Regexp.new(ingredients.join("|"), true)`

Answer (score 3):

For an array **a**, something like this should work:

```
a.each do |line|
    parts = /^([\d\s\.\/]+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)$/.match(line)
    # Do something with parts[1 .. 3]
end
```

For example:

```
a = [
    '1 1/3 cups all-purpose flour',
    '2 teaspoons ground cinnamon',
    '8 ounces shredded mozzarella cheese',
    '1.5 liters brandy',
]
puts "amount\tunits\tingredient"
a.each do |line|
    parts = /^([\d\s\.\/]+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)$/.match(line)
    puts parts[1 .. 3].join("\t")
end
```

Comment: + 1 Thanks for your answer, oddly enough your answer is like right on for the dumb way I described my problem, I don't think I was very clear, but your solution is actually really good for the way I described it.